# Store values in dictionary in the required format rather than strings when written from csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file ,and I am importing its data to a dictionary but the values ,I am getting are strings, instead of normal values.
My csv file in code editor looks like this

```
अनौपचारिक,0,,
मृत,-0.75,,
परवर्ती,0.125,,
```

In spreadsheet software(I am using Mac so pages) look like this-

```
 अनौपचारिक  0       
 मृत    -0.75       
 परवर्ती    0.125
```

Numeric values are in next cells.

Dictionary,I am obtaining after importing is below-

```
 {'अँअड़ी': '0',
  'अँकड़ा': '0',
  'अँकड़ी': '0',
 }
```

I want it to be stored as-

```
 {'अँअड़ी': 0,
  'अँकड़ा': 0,
  'अँकड़ी': 0,
 }
```

Values in the dictionary differs from the above 2 because it is writing randomly I suppose and I am pasting straight from the console.

My code for writing it -

```
data={}
with open('operate_to_dict.csv','r',newline='') as f:
reader=csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    data[row[0]]=row[1]
 pprint.pprint(data)
```

Comment: `data[row[0]] = int(row[1])`? you just want to cast the values of your dict to an `int`?

Comment: Thanks,I am feeling like an idiot

Comment: don't worry. happens all the time. to me anyway...